# if is working properly but elif throws an error

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am writing a python code(supplied);
but when I say 'open photos' everything works fine and it recognizes that I said 'open photos' but throws back except statement instead of 'elif listen() == "open photos": output'.Please help me.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import time
friday = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
friday.setProperty('rate', 150)
def listen():
     with mic as source:
         r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
         audio = r.listen(source)
         try:
           text =  r.recognize_google(audio)
           print(text)
           return text
         except sr.UnknownValueError:
          friday.say("sorry sir , could't do that")
          friday.runAndWait()
print("started!")
while 1:
    if listen() == "hello Jarvis":
        friday.say("hello sir")
        friday.runAndWait()
    elif listen() == "open photos":
            friday.say("opening")
            friday.runAndWait()
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Care to explain what that error is? You shouldn't need to listen twice, just set it to a variable before the if statement.

Comment: You should share the getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is better attention.  `listen` will consume the input; calling it a second time forces you to repeat the phrase.  Instead, pay attention the first time.  :-)

```
heard = listen()
if heard == "hello Jarvis":
    friday.say("hello sir")
    friday.runAndWait()
elif heard == "open photos":
    friday.say("opening")
    friday.runAndWait()
```

Note that your code is easier to read if you indent consistently: code at the same processing level, even between independent blocks, should be indented to the same level.